# Integration tests with REST Assured and Jetty

Tags: jetty, rest-assured

I have a REST API running in Jetty using eclipse' jetty maven plugin; and use rest-assured for integration test. for some my IT kept failing due to connection refused. I double checked the rest-assured dependencies are up to date, so now im wondering if the jetty are really running during the IT phase.  here are my code:

dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
  <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

jetty maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.1.v20140609</version>
        <configuration>
          <httpConnector>
            <port>8103</port>
          </httpConnector>
          <stopPort>8005</stopPort>
          <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>start-jetty</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>stop</goal>
              <goal>run-war</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
              <daemon>true</daemon>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>stop-jetty</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

IT code:

```
@Test
    public void testHead() throws Exception {
        //J-
        given()
            .port(PORT)
            .head(URL)   <-- /status
            .then()
            .statusCode(200);
        //J+
    }
```

the error message i see is:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.http.client.HttpClient$execute$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder.doRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1952)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:492)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:441)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder$request$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendHttpRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1374)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.SendRequestFilter.filter(SendRequestFilter.groovy:30)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:73)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.time.TimingFilter.filter(TimingFilter.java:56)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:73)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1574)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:159)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
```

Looks to me the jetty was not able to start at all? that's why the connect was refused?  is that because the versions of jetty-maven-plugin and rest-assured are not compatible?

Comment: any solution ?? i am also getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

This exception usually occurs when there is no service listening on the port that you are trying to connect to.

please check the following:

1. server down?
2. Server is not waiting/configured to get connection?
3. wrong port number while trying to connect?

Answer (score 0):

**I was struggling with integration test with rest assured using spring boot**

I was not sure how to start server temp and run IT and stop when not needed.

Start server(jetty) --> run integration test -- Stop  jetty ---

Thanks for ur code snippet (Jetty plugin) of pom(helpful for me and used it in my pom.xml)

I gone through link
https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/how-to-split-junit-tests-in-a-continuous-integration-environment and used following plugin for integration test

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>verify</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I also faced same problem which you have faced. got solution from here [testing spring boot rest application with restAssured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40665315/testing-spring-boot-rest-application-with-restassured) and implemented in my code

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MainControllerIT {

       @LocalServerPort
        private int port;

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
        RestAssured.port = port;
        //RestAssured.baseURI="http://localhost";// optional
        }

    @Test
    public void whenRequestGet_thenOK(){
        given().when().get("/").then().statusCode(200);
    }
}
```

**It workes!!!** Now my integration test run successfully without deploying war on external server(Tomcat)